# Adding Gradient Hides UILabel Text In UITableViewCell

Tags: ios5, uitableview, uilabel, cagradientlayer

I am trying to add gradient layer behind the UILabel's text which resides in a custom UITableViewCell. Problem is that gradient is hiding my label's text. I have already visited [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850149/adding-a-cggradient-as-sublayer-to-uilabel-hides-the-text-of-label) link, but it is not working for me.So how can I add it **behind the text layer**?

What I have done so far is:

```cs
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,  buyPrice_port.frame.size.width,  buyPrice_port.frame.size.height);
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)gainBackgroundColor1, (id)gainBackgroundColor2, nil];
    gradient.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.00], [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.70] , nil];
    [buyPrice_port.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];
    buyPrice_port.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Did you got any solution?

Comment: @YossiTsafar Sorry I don't remember. You can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4850506/437146) method though

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add a view behind the `UILabel` (i.e. add the label as a subview of the gradient view) and keep the label transparent.