# Gradient on a UILabel?

Tags: swift, uilabel, gradient, background-color

I am trying to create a `UILabel` that will have a gradient background color. I am wondering if there is a way to do this through the interface builder. If not, is there a way to accomplish this programmatically using the Swift programming language?

Any input or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: My answer here may help https://stackoverflow.com/a/53847223/4429457 Good luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not the same question, it seems the answer to this may help:

[How to Apply Gradient to background view of iOS Swift App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app)

You have to create a gradient layer and insert it as a sublayer programmatically.

Answer (score 10):

You actually can't put directly a gradient layer in a UILabel, since the text will dissapear. See [Adding a CGGradient as sublayer to UILabel hides the text of label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850149/adding-a-cggradient-as-sublayer-to-uilabel-hides-the-text-of-label)

You can use an UIView, put your UILabel inside it, and then add the gradient layer to the UIView like this.

[How to Apply Gradient to background view of iOS Swift App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24380535/how-to-apply-gradient-to-background-view-of-ios-swift-app)

Comment: since the text will dissapear... A pain in the neck. Creating a custom view is a nice suggestion +1