# Changing background of UILabels in UIStackView to gradient color

Tags: ios, iphone, uistackview

I am new to iOS development and I am working with the `UIStackView`.
When I use `StoryBoard` to create two `UILabels` as child objects of `UIStackView` the following code to make gradient backround color of each `UILabel` works fine.

```
UILabel *label;
for (int ii = 1; ii < 3; ii++) {
    label = [self.view viewWithTag:ii];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = label.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor yellowColor]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor grayColor]CGColor], nil];
    [label.layer insertSublayer:gradient atIndex:0];

    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:label.bounds];
    newLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    newLabel.text = label.text;
    [label addSubview:newLabel];
}
```

But when I create two `UILabels` programatically with using the code bellow,
my code above for making gradient background of each `UILabel` doesn't work and backround color stays white.
Can someone help me with this?

```
UILabel *myLabel;
myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[myLabel setText:@"text1"];
[myLabel setTag:1];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:myLabel];

myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
[myLabel setText:@"text2"];
[myLabel setTag:2];
[stackView addArrangedSubview:myLabel];
```

Comment: Can you see the labels in `UIStackView` using above code?

Comment: Yes, I can see the labels however with no gradient background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with the label bounds.  The following code adds a UIStackView and adds several UILabels with gradients.

```
const int STACK_WIDTH = 200;
const int NUM_LABELS = 3;
const int LABEL_WIDTH = STACK_WIDTH / NUM_LABELS;

UIStackView* stack = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, STACK_WIDTH, 100)];
stack.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
stack.distribution = UIStackViewDistributionFillProportionally;
stack.alignment = UIStackViewAlignmentLeading;
stack.spacing = LABEL_WIDTH;
stack.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
[self.view addSubview:stack];

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_LABELS; i++){
    UIView* myLabelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * LABEL_WIDTH, 0, LABEL_WIDTH, stack.frame.size.height)];

    CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    gradient.frame = myLabelView.bounds;
    gradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[[UIColor yellowColor]CGColor], (id)[[UIColor grayColor]CGColor], nil];
    gradient.startPoint = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    gradient.endPoint = CGPointMake(1, 0);
    [myLabelView.layer addSublayer:gradient];

    UILabel* myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myLabelView.bounds];
    myLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"label: %d", i];
    [myLabelView addSubview:myLabel];

    [stack addArrangedSubview:myLabelView];
}
```

Comment: When you do it this way, the text of UILabel stays covered by the gradient. That's why I use adding new UILabel as a subview of other UILabel - as suggested in this posting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4850149/adding-a-cggradient-as-sublayer-to-uilabel-hides-the-text-of-label

Comment: Yes my mistake, I'll edit my answer - are you still having issues?

Comment: Yes, I still have this issue.

Comment: Is it still the same problem?  I updated my answer again - does it work for you?  Maybe you can post more of your code, like how you've created your UIStackView.

Comment: Thank you, it works. It seams that the key was in setting spacing.... Thank you very much.